# Inductance in a set of circular concentric coils

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Suppose you have set of circular concentric solenoids like so:

[image: Text]

How would you calculate the overall inductance of these loops? Would it be the same as this formula:

[image: Text]

Or would the formula be modified? Thanks!

Comment: Are the coils connected together? What inductance? Self inductance? If so, of which coil? Mutual inductance? If so, between which pair of coils?

Comment: @Puk The coils are not connected, merely adjacent to one another. I'm trying to calculate the total energy using the formula 1/2 * L * I^2.

Comment: Then what is $I$? The current through which coil?

Comment: @Puk I presumed that 'I' was the overall current of all the coils. (The background ideology being that you would take the sum of the current of each coil and then square it in the formula) This sounds inaccurate though and I believe could be incorrect. What would be the correct implementation if I am incorrect?

Comment: The total current is not enough. You would need the current through each coil, and then the self inductance of each coil and the mutual inductance of each pair of coils.

Comment: @Puk How would this work relative to the above formula?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109459/discussion-between-dl19-and-puk).